# spring gateway: how to dynamically set URI and path based on request headers and path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

let's say i have incoming request:
host: `my-XXX.domain.com` and path `/YYY/ZZZ` and i want to route that request to uri `XXX.YYY.internal.domain.com/ZZZ`. how can i achieve it?

standard api doesn't seem to allow any kind of pattern extraction

```
builder.routes()
    .route{ it
            .header(xxx,xxx)
            .path("/*/**")
            .uri("i can't use here anything captured in header or path function")
    }
```

there is a function which gives me access to request and allow to return any URI

```
                        .filters{
                            it.changeRequestUri {
                                val service = it.request....
                                Optional.of(URI("http://...."))
                            }
                        }
                        .uri("https://this will be ignored")
```

but i can't set path there.

is there any existing api to simply achieve it or do i have to write custom filter? how to do it properly?

Comment: the uri attribute should not contain a path. Use a filter like `SetPath` or `RewritePath` to change the path.

Comment: @spencergibb both `SetPath` and `RewritePath` don't allow to set the path depending on incomming path or uri

Comment: They do. Here's rewrite https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-gateway-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demogateway/DemogatewayApplication.java#L34-L37 and Set Path https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#the-setpath-gatewayfilter-factory. You can also do the path `{myval}` in the `host()` predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what worked for me

```
.filters{
    it.changeRequestUri {
        val (service, environment, newPath) = computeUrlParts(it)
        Optional.of(URI("http://$environment$service.internal.my-company.com/$newPath"))
    }
}
.uri("http://postman-echo.com") //ignored
```

Comment: @piltrek can you provide more details if possible. Is the syntax is Java. I feel it's kind of different.

Comment: @RaviMCA it's kotlin